# How to get UNIX 'cp' command to recognize OS X alias?

Tags: macos, filesystems, cp

I am developing a backup utility on OS X, and I have noticed that my program is not copying aliases. Through some debugging, I have found that when you try to copy an alias with `cp` it acts as if the file does not exist.

Example:

```
cp -p "/Users/spurlock/Desktop/IT3 Backups/IT3 HD1/Users/spurlock/Library/Caches/Desktop/iPhoto Albums/Photos/2008-00070.2.JPG" .
cp: /Users/spurlock/Desktop/IT3 Backups/IT3 HD1/Users/spurlock/Library/Caches/Desktop/iPhoto Albums/Photos/2008-00070.2.JPG: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to get `cp` to recognize OS X alias? If not, how can I programmatically copy them (C, C++, Obj C)

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking at the error closely enough.

`cp` exists on the Macintosh and generally works great.  Your problem here appears to be that the file does not exist in the place where you expect it is.

Try doing:

```
ls "/Users/spurlock/Desktop/IT3 Backups/IT3 HD1/Users/spurlock/Library/Caches/Desktop/iPhoto Albums/Photos/2008-00070.2.JPG"
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Yes it works. The issue is that the file is an alias, I am sure that the files exist.

Comment: I just created an alias for a file in the Finder and copied it via "`cp`" and "`cp -p`" with no problems on my machine. I think something else is wrong with your file or that directory you're trying to read (maybe a permissions thing?)

Comment: Aha! It only fails to copy aliases that point to files that no longer exist. Doh. Thanks!

Comment: It would not do that for an actual alias file.  "cp" doesn't understand alias files or how to resolve them.  It would do that for a symbolic link (symlink) that no longer points to a real file. The Finder displays them pretty much identically, with the little curved arrow badge.

Comment: well... glad I was able to help you figure out the answer.